# Using Wordpress Redirection plugin to strip URL parameters

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce on Wordpress to run a small online shop and Google is crawling loads of page variations such as:

```
http://domain/page?orderby=rating&view=grid
http://domain/page?orderby=price&view=list
http://domain/page?orderby=date
```

As it stands there are more pages like this than products and it's likely that Google will consider some of them to be duplicate content.

I'm planning on using the Wordpress Redirection plugin to create some regexp rules so that I can redirect each of these variations to the main product page.  In other words, redirect:

```
http://domain/page?orderby=rating&view=grid
http://domain/page?orderby=rating&view=list


to:

http://domain/page
```

To do this I just need to split the URL at the whilst keeping the page part - I think ?.  How do I do this ?  I've searched around on the web but haven't found a specific example and I'm hopeless with regular expressions !

Thanks in advance

Phil

Comment: This question does not appear to be appropriate for StackOverflow (see "[What topics can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"). You might want to try asking it over on the WordPress StackExchange site: "[WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)".

Comment: OK thanks - will try over there ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RobertB. But also wanted to mention that you should research canonical URLs 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en